# Laptop HDD with Windows doesn't work on desktop

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop, desktop, system-restore

I've just assembled a new desktop PC and wanted to use my old laptop HDD with it but it won't start Windows 7.
It goes to a black screen with two options:

1. start Windows normally
2. run system restore

Option 1 just starts loading logo for 1 second and restarts

Option 2 fails to restore to previous date.

I also tried it with an even older laptop HDD from 2006 with all the same results!

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you actually run an install of Windows 7 using those disks on your new PC or did you just happen to have two HDDs that have some Windows version on them and you tried to boot them?

Comment: Are you trying to install Windows and instead of booting from DVD/USB you are booting from these HDD?

Answer (score 0):

Moving an existing Windows to another hardware configuration isn't easy. The main problem is drivers (particularly that of the storage controller).

Another problem that might arise is licensing errors. Many computers are shipped with OEM licenses, which aren't interchangeable across different hardware. Even when you have a full license, the other system is likely to be too different from the original (particularly when you have a different motherboard in there).

The best thing to do would be to just reinstall Windows so that it's made specifically for your new hardware configuration.